# Can docker compose build image from different Dockerfiles at the same folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

My containers should share the same source code folder.

But they should build from different Dockerfiles.

Is it possible to build them with docker-compose and build from different Dockerfiles at a time?

I wish there is a syntax like

> `build: . -f <<Dockerfile_ABC>` `build: . -f <<Dockerfile_CDE>`

```
abc:
  build: . -f <<Dockerfile_ABC>
  environment:
    - PROJECT=abc
  command: ruby abc/abc.rb
  volumes:
      - ./:/working_direcotry
  ports:
    - 5904:5904

cde:
  build: . -f <Dockerfile_CDE>
  environment:
    - PROJECT=cde
  command: ruby cde/cde.rb
  volumes:
      - ./:/working_direcotry
  ports:
    - 5902:5902
```

Comment: you should be fine to raise pull request to docker github directly for your idea

Comment: Is this a possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835905/docker-compose-using-multiple-dockerfiles-for-multiple-services. At first I misunderstood this question (ignored the docker-compose part) and wrote an answer. I deleted that answer now, and posted this comment instead haha.

Answer (score 27):

The following worked for me

```
abc:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.one
def:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.two
```

Of course you can tweak the context as needed if you have different contexts. I also use this to have separate Dockerfile.production versions to set things up differently for production versions of the app.

Comment: A bit trivial trick: in vsCode, it is better to use `one.dockerfile` instead of `Dockerfile.one`

Answer (score -1):

Just specify the name of the Dockerfile:

```
abc:
    build: path/to/Dockerfile_for_abc
```

Comment: My guess that the author want the same build context for all services. Once the Dockerfile is in the a different path, the build context changes to that path as well.

Comment: Answer is confusing about what are you specifying, it's not a 'name of the Dockerfile' its a completely different folder, specifying this as full path to another docerfile will lead to an error:
 `failed to read dockerfile: error from sender:  ..../Dockerfile_for_abc: not a directory`